# I am confused about this code, what is wrong with the code

Tags: python, function

[image]

It keep saying it is wrong, but I don't know what is wrong with it.
I also tried ==name==, or =name, none of these work.
Please help me.
I also tried the whole coding on IDLE and Jupyter, they all said there is a mistake with same part.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). The correct spelling is `if __name__ == '__main__':` with two underscores before and after `name` and `main`, and two equal signs.

Comment: please, use the code block to post you code

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

In Python, `==` checks whether two values are equal. `=` means to assign a value to a variable.

Answer (score -3):

1. It should be `__name__ == '__main__'`
2. The `__name__` is a special variable in python, If we try to run a file which is the main file the `__name__ == '__main__'` will check whether it is main file or not allows the file to execute.
3. `=` will assign value to the variable and `==` will check both are equal or not